# Groovy semantics for using a collection(list) as boolean

Tags: groovy

Groovy 2.14.12.

I believe I have interpreted the [Groovy semantics](https://groovy-lang.org/semantics.html#_boolean_expressions) for boolean correctly. For the below code, I have received a PR comment:

> There is no such semantic. You can check for yourself:
>
> > assert null == true
> > |
> > false
> > assert null == false
> > |
> > false null is neither true nor false. The test case you linked ensures that httpRequest.requestBody is always !null so it will
> > always pass

```
class HttpRequest {

    //Mandatory
    private final String url
    private final String httpMethod
    private final String requestContentType
    private final String acceptContentType

    //Optional
    private String requestBody
    private List<Integer> validResponseCodes

    HttpRequest(String url, String httpMethod, String requestContentType, String acceptContentType) {
        this.url = url
        this.httpMethod = httpMethod
        this.requestContentType = requestContentType
        this.acceptContentType = acceptContentType
    }

    void setRequestBody(String requestBody) {
        this.requestBody = requestBody
    }

    void setValidResponseCodes(List<Integer> validResponseCodes) {
        this.validResponseCodes = validResponseCodes
    }

    String getUrl() {
        return url
    }

    String getHttpMethod() {
        return httpMethod
    }

    String getRequestContentType() {
        return requestContentType
    }

    String getAcceptContentType() {
        return acceptContentType
    }

    String getRequestBody() {
        return requestBody
    }

    List<Integer> getValidResponseCodes() {
        return validResponseCodes
    }
}
```

Code in another class named HttpClient:

```
private Map getJenkinsHttpRequestParameters(HttpRequest httpRequest) {

        Map jenkinsHttpRequestMap =  [(JenkinsHttpRequest.URL): httpRequest.url,
                (JenkinsHttpRequest.HTTP_METHOD): httpRequest.httpMethod,
                (JenkinsHttpRequest.CONTENT_TYPE): httpRequest.requestContentType,
                (JenkinsHttpRequest.ACCEPT_TYPE): httpRequest.acceptContentType,
               ]

        
        script.println "requestBody: ${httpRequest.requestBody}"
        
        if (httpRequest.requestBody) {
            
            script.println "if requestBody evaluated to true"

            jenkinsHttpRequestMap.put(JenkinsHttpRequest.REQUEST_BODY, httpRequest.requestBody)
        }

        
        script.println "validResponseCodes: ${httpRequest.validResponseCodes}"
        
        if (httpRequest.validResponseCodes) {
            
            script.println "if validResponseCodes evaluated to true"

            jenkinsHttpRequestMap.put(JenkinsHttpRequest.VALID_RESPONSE_CODES,
                                      httpRequest.validResponseCodes.join(',')
                                     )
        }

        return jenkinsHttpRequestMap
    }
```

Test Case:1

```
@Test
    void "successfully_execute_invokeSNAPRestAPI_with_HttpRequest_without_optional"() {

        when:
        Object stepScript = loadScript([(RequestResponseMock.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS):
                                                HttpConstants.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_OK,
                                        (RequestResponseMock.HTTP_RESPONSE_CONTENT):
                                                RequestResponseMock.AUTHORIZE_APPROVED_RESULT,
        ])

        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest(RequestResponseMock.SNAP_SERVER_URL_VALUE,
                HttpConstants.HTTP_METHODS.PUT.name(),
                HttpConstants.REQUEST_CONTENT_TYPE_JSON,
                HttpConstants.ACCEPT_TYPE_JSON
        )

        and:
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(stepScript)
        Map response = httpClient.invokeSNAPRestAPI(httpRequest)

        then:
        assert stepScript
        assert response
        assert response.get(HttpConstants.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE) == HttpConstants.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_OK
    }
```

The test case passes, output:

```
requestBody: null
validResponseCodes: null
```

Test Case:2

```
@Unroll
    @Test
    void "successfully_execute_invokeSNAPRestAPI_with_HttpRequest_optional_parameters"() {

        when:
        Object stepScript = loadScript([(RequestResponseMock.HTTP_RESPONSE_STATUS):
                                                HttpConstants.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_OK,
                                        (RequestResponseMock.HTTP_RESPONSE_CONTENT):
                                                RequestResponseMock.AUTHORIZE_APPROVED_RESULT,
                                       ])

        HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest(RequestResponseMock.SNAP_SERVER_URL_VALUE,
                HttpConstants.HTTP_METHODS.PUT.name(),
                HttpConstants.REQUEST_CONTENT_TYPE_JSON,
                HttpConstants.ACCEPT_TYPE_JSON
        )
        if(setOptionalParams) {
            httpRequest.setRequestBody(requestBody)
            httpRequest.setValidResponseCodes(validResponseCodes)
        }

        and:
        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient(stepScript)
        Map response = httpClient.invokeSNAPRestAPI(httpRequest)

        then:
        assert stepScript
        assert response
        assert response.get(HttpConstants.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE) == HttpConstants.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_OK

        where:
        setOptionalParams | requestBody                                                   | validResponseCodes
        false             | JsonOutput.toJson(RequestResponseMock.NORMAL_CHANGE_PAYLOAD)  | VALID_RESPONSES
        true              | JsonOutput.toJson(RequestResponseMock.NORMAL_CHANGE_PAYLOAD)  | VALID_RESPONSES
        true              | EMPTY_STRING                                                  | VALID_RESPONSES
        true              | null                                                          | VALID_RESPONSES
        true              | JsonOutput.toJson(RequestResponseMock.NORMAL_CHANGE_PAYLOAD)  | null
        true              | JsonOutput.toJson(RequestResponseMock.NORMAL_CHANGE_PAYLOAD)  | []
    }
```

These tests pass as well, output:

```
requestBody: {"description":"Change notes for new version:","short_description":"Deploy new version" }
if requestBody evaluated to true
validResponseCodes: [200, 201, 400]
if validResponseCodes evaluated to true

requestBody: 
validResponseCodes: [200, 201, 400]
if validResponseCodes evaluated to true

requestBody: null
validResponseCodes: [200, 201, 400]
if validResponseCodes evaluated to true

requestBody: {"description":"Change notes for new version:","short_description":"Deploy new version" }
if requestBody evaluated to true
validResponseCodes: null

requestBody: {"description":"Change notes for new version:","short_description":"Deploy new version" }
if requestBody evaluated to true
validResponseCodes: []
```

Edit:

```
5. The Groovy Truth
Groovy decides whether a expression is true or false by applying the rules given below.

assert true
assert !false
5.2. Collections and Arrays
Non-empty Collections and arrays are true.

assert [1, 2, 3]
assert ![]
```

So, if a List is not initialized at all(in the above HttpRequest object), it (practically evaluates to false), how does one assume that it will evaluate to false? Is it because if Groovy is coercing it to false?

Comment: Are you asking why your reviewer rejected your code? At first glance you never compare requestBody but use it to send a request. You might be better off asking the reviewer than SO.

Comment: Or if you think, this is a good SO question, then please trim it down showing the actual problem and provide the errors/stacktraces you see.

Comment: Edited the original question to get an idea about Groovy truth.